# Get the first 300 character of ckeditor content without tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am using CKEDITOR and after the user enters in the description I want to take the first 300 characters and place them within a summary text box. I am using the code below to make the content move after moving from the description ckeditor box. When i alert the value it will include < p > tags. I cannot strip the string incase the user intends to use them.

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'property_description' );
CKEDITOR.instances['property_description'].on('blur', function() {
    var value = CKEDITOR.instances['property_description'].getData();
    alert(value);
});
```

Comment: use `.substring()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using plain javascript:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('property_description');
CKEDITOR.instances['property_description'].on('blur', function() {
    var html = CKEDITOR.instances['property_description'].getData();
    var tmp = document.createElement('div');

    // Strip HTML
    tmp.innerHTML = html;
    var value = tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText;

    // alert truncated value
    alert(value.substring(0, 300);
});
```

---

Using jQuery:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('property_description');
CKEDITOR.instances['property_description'].on('blur', function() {
    var html = CKEDITOR.instances['property_description'].getData();
    var value = $('<div/>', { html: html }).text();

    // alert truncated value
    alert(value.substring(0, 300);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, Im using the jquery version. What is happening on the var value line there?

Comment: First argument '<div/>' tell jQuery to create div element. Next argument is a object with properties to this element. Then we call text() to this element to fetch plain text without any HTML.

Comment: Ahh yes I see now whats happening. Thanks for the help and explination

Answer (score 0):

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'property_description' );
CKEDITOR.instances['property_description'].on('blur', function() {
    var value = CKEDITOR.instances['property_description'].getData();
    var chars = (((value.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "")).replaceHtmlEntites()).replace(/ /g, '')).substring(0, 300);
        alert(chars)
});


String.prototype.replaceHtmlEntites = function () {
    var s = this;
    var translate_re = /&(nbsp|amp|quot|lt|gt);/g;
    var translate = {"nbsp": "", "\t": "", "amp": "&", "quot": "\"", "lt": "<", "gt": ">"};
    return ( s.replace(translate_re, function (match, entity) {
        return translate[entity];
    }) );
};
```

Try this with jQuery

Comment: Extending native objects is bad practice.

Comment: @Adshi Can u pls explain?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice